# Encryption - Wrong data when decrypting

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm working on communicating with a server and I've reached the final stage, where after negotiating keys and setting the session key, I send an encrypted message and the server answers back.
Currently, we're working with AES-256 CBC, with a random IV that gets sent to the server and I locally store. The problem that I'm currently facing is when I decrypt the data I got from the server:

```
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(cipher.getIV(), 0, 16));
//Get the array after the 7 bytes from the header
byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(sbResponse.toString().getBytes(), 7, sbResponse.toString().length());
```

When I try to decrypt that parsed array, any of the following happen, however, the response from the server does not vary in length or content at all:

- I can't decrypt it, because of the following error:

  ```
  javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
  ```
- I can't decrypt it, this error comes up:

  ```
  javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when   decrypting with padded cipher
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
  ```
- I can decrypt it, certain blocks come up fine, but some of them, have weird characters among clear text:

  ```
  k¤kC­²O©æÖ—Õw½QøX»ÌEXøÀWHÌËùtiÓaÚo at?the application
  ```
- Everything comes up just fine.

So, I have to make a bunch of calls until I get a clean response from the server.

What I've noticed is that the server does change the IV on its end, however, on my end, the IV always remains the same when I ask the Cipher for it, so I really don't know where else to look.

Here's an excerpt of the code that gets the response from the server:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (ConnectionStatus.LISTENING.equals(status)) {

            if (in.ready()) {
                sb.append((char) in.read());
            } else {
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    status = ConnectionStatus.OPEN;
                }
            }
        }

        if (ConnectionStatus.TIMEOUT.equals(status)) {
            status = ConnectionStatus.OPEN;
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea on what might be happening?

Let me know if you need further details, code or anything.

Comment: It looks to me that some of the data isn't being transmitted, or you aren't stitching it together properly...

Comment: Definitely looks like a transmission error.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I've checked and the data is coming on its entirity.

Comment: Key, IV, cipher are all negotiated correctly?

Comment: Check the string length before and after transmission.

Comment: Yes, the server receives the same IV and Key that I have locally. The only difference is that the IV varies on the server side, while mine remains the same.
Anyways, I'm going to add a snippet of how I'm receiving the data from the server.

Comment: It seems I'm missing a byte in certain tries.

Comment: The data transmitted is binary data, so you shouldn't use `String` methods for it, or it will get mangled (unless it's further encoded to printable data)

Comment: Just added the code, however, this problem only comes up when encrypted data is in the equation, since I'm able to send and receive 2 messages before this last one.

Comment: The fact that the IVs don't sync could be a problem as well.

Comment: @bassprodukt the messages you're sending are text messages, right?

Comment: There are some specific bytes and text as well, I'm writing the bytes to the socket outputStream directly. There is no problem with that as the server gives me an acknoledgement of the integrity of my data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21287/discussion-between-bassprodukt-and-jan-dvorak)

Comment: HTTP is perfectly capable of sending/receiving binary data. You should either handle binary data, or you should use an encoding such as base64 over your binary data to make it ASCII compatible text.

Comment: Got it working, it was related to the StringBuilder thing! :) Thank you so much. 
Someone should provide an actual answer, so I accept it :P.

Comment: @JanDvorak this one is for you I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with storing binary data into a `String`.

If the `InputStreamReader` expects UTF-8, it most likely encounters invalid data since most binary streams are not valid UTF-8. Data is lost when the reader encounters a sequence of bytes that is not a valid character.

There are at least two or three solutions:

- Switch to the underlying `InputStream` for binary data. Since an `InputStreamReader` may perform buffering, this is problematic - even if this might happen with some charsets only ([`To enable the efficient conversion of bytes to characters, more bytes may be read ahead from the underlying stream than are necessary to satisfy the current read operation.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29))
- Always treat data as binary, and only if you expect textual data, [convert the data to String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).
- Encode the encrypted message to text before transmission, and decode it after receiving. There are several standard encoding schemes or you may roll your own. Here are some:

  - [Hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) - not exactly efficient (4 bits per character) but [easier to implement manually](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString%28long,%20int%29).
  - [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) - the de-facto standard in binary data encoding (6 bits per character). While not a part of the JFC (yet), [there's at least one library for that](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html).
  - [Ascii85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) - the top notch in encoding density to printable text (6.4 bits per character), if you can find [a library for that](http://java.net/projects/ascii85codec). It's not widely used.